# Copy branch to master and push to remote

Tags: git

On my `master` branch I have a lot of files that I dont need:

```
good_file1
good_file2
bad_file1
bad_file2
good_file3
```

On my `temp` branch I have only good filed:

```
good_file1
good_fil2
good_file3
```

I want to have `master` branch exactly the same as `temp` branch.

What I do is:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard new15
git push origin master
```

And I am getting

```
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to ''
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

But now, when I do `git pull` I am pulling bad_files. Also, I can't use `force`, because branch is protected. What should I do?

Comment: You should use `git rebase` then pull the remote and then `git rebase apply` after.

Comment: or you can just checkout ot the master branch and delete the files :)

Comment: If you can't force push `master` (which is most likely a good thing, and a safety precaution), then hard resetting to some other commit, rebasing, etc., won't be possible for that branch.  So, you'll have to find some other way to proceed.

Comment: @LazarNikolic there are thousand of files.

Comment: @dafie OK...but perhaps are those files are contained within a much smaller directory structure?  E.g. could you kill one folder and take out hundreds of files?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no. I can't do that. Multiple folders and subfolders.

Comment: The only options for you which I see are a) taking the suggestion of @Lazar and manually deleting the files, or b) maybe merging that other branch into `master`.  But, in the latter case, you could still end up with hundreds of merge conflicts, so it might not help anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Seriously? There is no better way? I could also copy all files from `temp` branch and paste it to `master` after pulling. But there must be a better solution..

Comment: Maybe we could take a step back and ask how you ended up having to make such a large change to one of your branches.  This could indicate bad branching strategy, or other bad planning.  In my Git travels, I seldom have a need to do such a large operation.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably just `git checkout master && git merge new15`. This will merge `new15` branch into master, applying all changes from `new15` branch onto the master branch, which includes removing the files that were removed on `new15` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using github, you should make a pull request, but if not:

You want to merge your branch into master.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge temp
git push origin master
```

check out https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging